# Will using c_str on a temp still fail when returned as QString?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, memory, qt5

I know about dangling pointers when using c_str wrongly. like this:

```
const char* str_ptr = functionReturningString().c_str();
// str_ptr is invalid, as the returned string from the function was temporary, and c_str simply points to that array.
```

I would like to know if this still applies to this code (C++11, Qt 5.5)

```
 QString UUId::toString () const
 {
    return to_string (_uuid).c_str();
 }
```

This is using the `to_string` function [from boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html#to_string)s uuid class.

it returns a `std::string`. This is a temporary object, and I expect `c_str()` to be dangerous.

Does the return type `QString` change this somehow? I am not sure if that will actually mean:

`return QString(to_string (_uuid).c_str());` (I'm just guessing)

which should create a copy (if you look at [QString (const char *)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-7) constructor) if I'm not mistaking.

**Question**: Is it safe? Or is the temp destroyed before the `QString` is constructed?

Comment: You could always use [`QString::fromStdString`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromStdString).

Comment: I know. I just want to know if the 2nd code block is safe or not. And how I can be sure.

Comment: It will not create a copy (it will create a new instance of QString but it is not a copy), this is safe but you can go explicit if you are unsure

Comment: You use implicitly `QString(const char *str)` constructor, which is safe.

Comment: The `return` statement needs to return a `QString` object. To do this the compiler will generated code to implicitly construct such an object from the  `const char*` that is used in the expression. In short, this is perfectly safe and fine.

Comment: Thank you @Slava for clarification that it's not a copy. Thanks programmer dude.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question

> Is it safe? Or is the temp destroyed before the `QString` is constructed?

```
QString UUId::toString () const
 {
    return to_string (_uuid).c_str();
 }
```

It is **safe**.

As the OP already mentioned, the result of `std::string::c_str()` is valid only as long as the corresponding `std::string` is unchanged (which includes not deleted).

The function has to return a `QString` and the `return` is called with a `const char*`.
The compiler will accept it if it finds a conversion from `const char*` to `QString`.
It will under certain conditions:

> [**Qstring::QString(const char *str)**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-7)
>
> Constructs a string initialized with the 8-bit string str. The given const char pointer is converted to Unicode using the fromUtf8() function.
>
> You can disable this constructor by defining QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII when you compile your applications. This can be useful if you want to ensure that all user-visible strings go through QObject::tr(), for example.

So, the question boils down to:

Does the `std::string` returned from `to_string()` live long enough to feed the constructor of `QString` with a pointer to its internal raw string?

It does.

From [cppreference – **Temporary object lifetime**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime):

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created, and if multiple temporary objects were created, they are destroyed in the order opposite to the order of creation. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception.

The full expression is in this case `to_string (_uuid).c_str()` (i.e. everything after `return` and before `;`).

---

To make this a little bit more explicit and robust (e.g. independent of whether `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII` is defined or not), I would write it as:

```
QString UUId::toString() const
{
  return QString::fromUtf8(to_string(_uuid).c_str());
}
```

but

```
QString UUId::toString() const
{
  return QString::fromStdString(to_string(_uuid));
}
```

should be rather equivalent because this will assume UTF-8 encoded contents of the passed argument as well. ([QString::fromStdString()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromStdString))

Answer (score 1):

The minimized version of your code is:

```
QString toString(const boost::uuids::uuid &uuid)
{
  return to_string(uuid).c_str();
}
```

This is safe because you're using `c_str()` just to initialize the contents of a `QString`. `QString` treats the C string as UTF-8 and initialized its internal UTF-16 storage by transcoding from UTF-8 to UTF-16. This of course copies all data, so by the time the full expression being returned finishes evaluating, the `QString` is constructed. Only then is the `std::string` you're accessing via `c_str()` destroyed.

What `return` here does is really as follows:

```
QString toString(const boost::uuids::uuid &uuid)
{
  return QString(to_string(uuid).c_str());
}
```

Again: the destructors run *after* the full expression has been evaluated the full expression is the `QString` constructor invocation. So, the temporary `std::string` has to be alive until the `QString` finishes constructing.

And this `QString` construction is *always* a copy. No matter where the C string comes from, it will be copied while it's being transcoded to UTF-16. In other words: the copy is not bit-identical, but is Unicode Code-Point identical. It results in a UTF-16 representation of the Unicode Code Points that were represented by the UTF-8 encoding in the C string. Code Points can be thought of as 32-bit integers, in some simplification.